# View overlapped by another view

Tags: android

Is there a way to know if a view is overlapped by another view? Like in RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think only by hand.

ie, walk the hierachy of the views and at each level of the tree, get the rects of each view and compare for intersection.

Comment: Is this the simplest solution? Isn't there a method like "isOverlapped" or something?

Answer (score 0):

You Have to use Android Developer tool - Hierarchy-Viewer,

[Check this developer site link.](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/hierarchy-viewer.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I mean programatically. When view A is over view B view B must become invisible.